# Creating reports in ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an Excel Sheet and I am trying to convert it into a Crystal Report. I am working on `SAP Crystal Reports`.

This is how my report should look like
[image]

[image]

I am totally new to `Crystal Reports` so I have following things to ask:

1. Can I develop this kind of report using `SAP crystal Report`?
2. Can anybody provide links to where I can start from `scratch` to `advance` level? I did some research myself, but almost all of the tutorials are mostly `beginners` level that takes you through developing your first report. Didn't come across something like this(of this format).

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you found answers to these questions? It would really help if you could post an answer. Thank you.